# How to save tkinter checkbox and Entry status and load it in next running

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on tkinter python file with some changeable values using `checkbox` and `Entry` widgets, so i need to save these widgets state and values and load it in the next file execution, and this is my python code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

gui=Tk()

firstVal = IntVar(value=90)
secVal = IntVar(value=1)
thirdVal = IntVar(value=0)

def apply_conf():
    try:
        int(textBox.get())
        messagebox.showinfo(title="done", message="your done")
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(title="error", message="please enter valid number")


        
labelPlist = Label(gui,text = "first value  ")
labelPlist.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=10, pady=4, sticky='w')

labelPlist = Label(gui,text = "second value")
labelPlist.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=10, pady=4, sticky='w')

labelPlist = Label(gui,text = "third value ")
labelPlist.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=10, pady=4, sticky='w')

textBox=Entry(gui, width=8, borderwidth=0)
textBox.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=7, pady=4, sticky='w')


checkBox = Checkbutton(gui,variable = secVal, borderwidth=0 )
checkBox.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=7, pady=4, sticky='w')

checkBox1 = Checkbutton(gui, variable = thirdVal, borderwidth=0 )
checkBox1.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=7, pady=4, sticky='w')

buttonDel=Button(gui, height=0, width=16, text="Apply all Changes", borderwidth=0, command=lambda: apply_conf())
buttonDel.grid(column=0, row=9,padx=10,pady=12)

buttonExit=Button(gui, height=0, width=8, text="Exit", borderwidth=0,  command=gui.destroy) 
buttonExit.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=20,pady=4)


gui.geometry("220x190")

mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far to save the status?

Comment: write to file then read from file, pretty simple: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/ <- some info

Comment: You can save them in a file, maybe you can save it in JSON format so everything is more organized.
See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: @scotty3785-  i tried to export my variable in text file and import them , but it's not working as i expect.

Comment: @Matiiss - i need to save them as python variable ( var = value ) each variable in one line, so this method not working for me.

Comment: is there any particular reason you need that? also then you can manually add variables and read their value from file. what exactly did not work when you tried saving and reading those values from file?, also provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use pickle for this purpose. I modified slightly your code to exemplify how it works in case of the first variable:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pickle
import numpy as np

gui=Tk()

try:
    firstVal_store=pickle.load(open("storage1.p","rb"))
    firstVal=IntVar(value=firstVal_store)
    secVal = IntVar(value=1)
    thirdVal = IntVar(value=0)
    print('Initial values loaded from memory!')
except:
    firstVal = IntVar(value=90)
    secVal = IntVar(value=1)
    thirdVal = IntVar(value=0)

def apply_conf():
    try:
        int(textBox.get())
        messagebox.showinfo(title="done", message="your done")
        #let's save the variables...
        firstVal_store=textBox.get()
        pickle.dump(firstVal_store,open("storage1.p","wb"))
        print("Stored!",firstVal_store)

    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror(title="error", message="please enter valid number")



labelPlist = Label(gui,text = "first value  ")
labelPlist.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=10, pady=4, sticky='w')

labelPlist = Label(gui,text = "second value")
labelPlist.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=10, pady=4, sticky='w')

labelPlist = Label(gui,text = "third value ")
labelPlist.grid(column=0, row=7, padx=10, pady=4, sticky='w')

textBox=Entry(gui, width=8, borderwidth=0)
textBox.insert(0,firstVal.get())
textBox.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=7, pady=4, sticky='w')


checkBox = Checkbutton(gui,variable = secVal, borderwidth=0 )
checkBox.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=7, pady=4, sticky='w')

checkBox1 = Checkbutton(gui, variable = thirdVal, borderwidth=0 )
checkBox1.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=7, pady=4, sticky='w')

buttonDel=Button(gui, height=0, width=16, text="Apply all Changes", borderwidth=0, command=lambda: apply_conf())
buttonDel.grid(column=0, row=9,padx=10,pady=12)

buttonExit=Button(gui, height=0, width=8, text="Exit", borderwidth=0,  command=gui.destroy)
buttonExit.grid(column=0, row=10, padx=20,pady=4)


gui.geometry("220x190")

mainloop()
```

...if you find it convenient, simply extend the idea to cover also the other variables.

Comment: Why use pickle instead of just saving it to a file. As in: `with open(...) as file: file.write(firstVal_store)`

Comment: It's working for me, i tried to vote your answer but (i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote), thank you so much.